# How to create a calculated (average and conditional) in sql?

Tags: sql, average, calculated-columns

[image: Raw Data]

I want to use the raw data (above) to create a new table (below)

[image: New Table]

Comment: Do you want to create a query for this ?

Comment: Please post your examples as formatted text, not images.  Also, please don't cut of the headers half way though *(your expected results have a column for `Value from`...)*.  Please also include the logic for each calculation you're attempting, and the code you've tried so far, how and why it failed, including error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a query for this then it can simply be achieved using group by

```
SELECT Name, Sum(Value) * 1.0/Count(Name), Sum(Value)/Count(Name)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Name
```